# bash script about filter more keywords

Tags: shell-script, scripting

Thanks for your time.

I want to filter more than one keyword01 (keyword02, keyword03....) in the bash script as below. How can I get this ?

All keywords alert to send to same E-mail address is OK.

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log | while read line do case "$line" in
        *"keyword01"*) echo "$line" | mutt -s "Email notice title" address@gmail.com;
        ;;    esac 
done
```

Comment: Do you want to send one separate email for each line that contains a keyword (akin to what you currently do), or do you want to extract all lines that contains any keywords and mail them all in one message?

Comment: Just sent only one Email address is OK for all keyword. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log |
  awk -v cmd='exec mutt -s "Email notice title" address@gmail.com' '
    /keyword1|keyword2/ {print | cmd; close(cmd)}'
```

In general, I'd avoid a shell loop to process text, but you could also do:

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log |
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    case "$line" in
      (*"keyword1"* | *"keyword2"*) 
        printf '%s\n' "$line" |
          mutt -s "Email notice title" address@gmail.com;;
    esac 
  done
```

In `zsh`, you can also use `*("keyword1"|"keyword2")*` instead. In `ksh` or `bash -O extglob`, `*@("keyword1"|"keyword2")*`.

[That Q&A argues that using a loop to process text is bad practice](/q/169716), but here we do need to run a command on those lines, it's not only about text processing, and that's the shell job to run commands.

Here, the reading of the file and matching of the text is less efficiently done than with `awk`, but the running of `mutt` is more efficient as `awk` does call a shell to interpret the command line to run and run `mutt`.

Note that `tail -f file` is short for `tail -n 10 -f file`, just like `tail file` is short for `tail -n 10 file`. That is, it prints the last 10 lines of the file and then enters the *follow* mode where it prints all that's added to the file afterwards.

Here, it seems to me you should use either `tail -n+1 -f file` to print the whole file and *following*, or `tail -n0 -f file` to only print what is going to be added to the file from now on.

See also the `-F` option found in some `tail` implementations, that detect renames. `/var/log/auth.log` often ends up renamed to `/var/log/auth.log.1` upon rotation and a new `/var/log/auth.log` created anew. `tail -f` would carry on watching the same file (now renamed) while you would want to switch to the new `/var/log/auth.log` like `tail -F` does.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer, so much detail you let me know. I test the script, the result is good.

Comment: @HKC;  if you consider the answer good, you should also upvote it (some accepted answers with a low score can be considered 'not appropriate', so upvoting when the answer is correct and helped you helps making it less ambiguous)

Comment: @OlivierDulac, you need at least 15 point reputation to be able to  upvote.

Comment: I have enough point to upvote! THX ALL !